Import class and dll files in Gradle project
I've just purchased an RFID Writer that comes with an SDK, the problem is the SDK isn't a .jar file, but these:

How can I import these to my Gradle (Kotlin) project?
I'm using Intellij IDEA.

You need to research on using JNI to interact with natively compiled code in form of DLL. This S.O. post is a good place to start. There is also a concise YouTube tutorial. Even GPT somehow (uncharacteristically) gave a decent explanation you should be able to follow with some manual effort. Good luck.

Also: You should read the documentation included in the SDK package (from your attached link), the author literally uses JNI in the corresponding Java classes. Once you have a decent understanding of JNI, you'll see there's a C++ Source Code folder included in the whole SDK package as well (not just the Java SDK v1.0 folder) - I believe that is the underlying C++ wrapper containing the definitions prescribed in the SDK your JNI code will need for "translating" into Java.

Foreign Function and Memory API is the modern approach over JNI.


Copy the dll files into your project folder
Copy Reader09.java into your main folder (the .class file is not needed)
Before the app starts, load the libraries:

    System.loadLibrary("Basic")
    System.loadLibrary("UHF_Reader09")

Now you can call the methods from Reader09 class.
Thanks to NitronHX for the guidance.
